# Magento 2 USPS throws error on frontend

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, usps

I have a Magento 2.3.4 site running. UPS Shipping calculates shipping costs correctly on front-end checkout, however, USPS returns an error. I have set debug to "on" and the error logs say that my user name and password are incorrect but this is not the case. I can log into usps.com fine with these creds and they also worked on on my old Magento 1.9.3 site.

I've found this question posted online in various places but haven't found an answer other than review the logs. But these are inconclusive so far.

Does anyone know any tips to get this working? My customers used USPS 9/10 on my Mage1.9 site so Id like to get it running.

Below is the latest entry to the shipping error log.

```
[2020-06-02 01:04:54] main.ERROR: '401 Unauthorized' [] []
[2020-06-02 01:04:54] main.DEBUG: array (
  'request' => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RateV4Request USERID="****"><Revision>2</Revision><Package ID="0"><Service>ALL</Service><ZipOrigination>94707</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>94544</ZipDestination><Pounds>2</Pounds><Ounces>0.0000000000</Ounces><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Machinable>true</Machinable></Package></RateV4Request>
',
  'result' => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Number>80040B1A</Number><Description>Authorization failure.  Perhaps username and/or password is incorrect.</Description><Source>USPSCOM::DoAuth</Source></Error>',
) [] []
[2020-06-02 01:14:03] main.ERROR: '401 Unauthorized' [] []
[2020-06-02 01:14:03] main.DEBUG: array (
  'request' => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RateV4Request USERID="****"><Revision>2</Revision><Package ID="0"><Service>ALL</Service><ZipOrigination>94707</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>94544</ZipDestination><Pounds>2</Pounds><Ounces>0.0000000000</Ounces><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Machinable>true</Machinable></Package></RateV4Request>
',
  'result' => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Number>80040B1A</Number><Description>Authorization failure.  Perhaps username and/or password is incorrect.</Description><Source>USPSCOM::DoAuth</Source></Error>',
) [] []
[2020-06-02 01:14:57] main.ERROR: '401 Unauthorized' [] []
[2020-06-02 01:14:57] main.DEBUG: array (
  'request' => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RateV4Request USERID="****"><Revision>2</Revision><Package ID="0"><Service>Priority</Service><ZipOrigination>94707</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>94544</ZipDestination><Pounds>2</Pounds><Ounces>0.0000000000</Ounces><Container>PADDED FLAT RATE ENVELOPE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Machinable>true</Machinable></Package></RateV4Request>
',
  'result' => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Number>80040B1A</Number><Description>Authorization failure.  Perhaps username and/or password is incorrect.</Description><Source>USPSCOM::DoAuth</Source></Error>',
) [] []
[2020-06-02 01:16:43] main.ERROR: '401 Unauthorized' [] []
[2020-06-02 01:16:43] main.DEBUG: array (
  'request' => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RateV4Request USERID="****"><Revision>2</Revision><Package ID="0"><Service>ALL</Service><ZipOrigination>94707</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>94544</ZipDestination><Pounds>2</Pounds><Ounces>0.0000000000</Ounces><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Machinable>false</Machinable></Package></RateV4Request>
',
  'result' => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Number>80040B1A</Number><Description>Authorization failure.  Perhaps username and/or password is incorrect.</Description><Source>USPSCOM::DoAuth</Source></Error>',
) [] []
```

Thanks

[image: Here is a screenshot of my backend confs]

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out in the end. It's frustratinly simple. I had my USPS shipping account details in there when I needed the user and password from the shipping APIs registration at [https://registration.shippingapis.com](https://registration.shippingapis.com/)

You need to register there and they send you an email containing a username and password in a format like this:

```
For Company:  My Company Name
Your Username is 070KOBIO8784
Your Password is 698TE88FH215
```

These are not real credentials, just an example of the format.

Once I entered those details it all worked fine. Somehow I missed this nuance or its not very well documented.

Just go here and sign up https://registration.shippingapis.com/